# Django - Create and add multiple xml to zip, and download as attachment

Tags: django, xml, zip

I am learner, and trying to build code to in which user has option to download the zip file that contains multiple .xlm files, which are created on the bases of database.

I have been able to create below code to download single xml file. But struggling to get multiple files packed in zipped format(for each row of database).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 def export_to_xml(request):
 listings = mydatabase.objects.all()
 root = ET.Element('listings')
 for item in listings:
     price = ET.Element('price')
     price.text = str(item.Name)
     offer = ET.Element('offer', attrib={'id': str(item.pk)})
     offer.append(price)
     root.append(offer)
     tree = ET.ElementTree(root)        
 response = HttpResponse(ET.tostring(tree.getroot()), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.xml"'

 return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Got the solution by using following approach

```
byteStream = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(byteStream, mode='w',) as zf:
# your code
zf.writestr()       
response = HttpResponse(byteStream.getvalue(), content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=finename.zip"
```